# How to handle object property changes in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bind

I have an object with `id` and `name` like this:

```
function format(id){
  return '(' + id + ')';
}

function MyObject(id){
  this.id = id;
  this.text = format(id);
}
```

I'm using angular and I have something like this in html:

```
<input ng-model="myObject.id" type="text">{{myObject.text}}
```

Using this code I can bind `id` to `input`, but `text` will not been changed. I need to use 'ng-change' to track object id changes. But I believe that here should be a way to make this process automatic in angular.

So, my question is "Is it possible to bind changes of the object property to the function call without `ng-change`?"

P.S. And I have an array of such objects, so I don't want to use `$scope.$watch()` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a property on it with getter.

```
function MyObject(id){
    this.id = id;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'text', {
        get: function () { return '(' + this.id + ')'; }
    });
}
```

to read more about Object.defineProperty access this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)